# Custom Play-button for embedded YouTube-videos

Tags: youtube, custom-controls, customization

I'm currently working on a project for a cycling site, where they have a small list of workout songs. Some of these songs have a link to a YouTube-video, so you can hear the song.

I have to make it, so in the overview of the songs, there is a small playbutton, which, when clicked, play the selected youtube-video. But the video should be hidden, so you only hear the music.

When clicked, the button changes to a pause or a stop-button, so you can stop the music again.

But i can figure out the guidelines on youtube or other medias.
So I hope i can get some help here.

The site has to load a minimum of 10 YouTube-videos, and all of them should have a custom play/stop-button. So can anyone help me with that? :)

Thanks

-Thomas

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/104932/how-to-watch-youtube-downloading-only-the-audio-stream seems to indicate that's there not an easy way to do this. Does the You Tube API even allow this?

Comment: http://code.google.com/intl/da/apis/youtube/youtube_player_demo.html - it sure looks like there is someway to make a custom play/stop-button. Just can't figure out how I'll get this to work with more that one youtube-video. And to hide they player you can just use style="display: none;".

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$yt_video = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AfgdUfDgCq8";

$jw = <<< EOF

<script type='text/javascript' src='jwplayer.js'></script>
<div id='mediaspace' style="display:none;visibility:hidden;">This text will be replaced</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
    'flashplayer': 'http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf',
    'file': '{$yt_video}',
    'controlbar': 'bottom',
    'width': '1',
    'height': '1',
    'autostart': 'true'
  });
</script>
EOF;

echo $jw;

?>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('mediaspace').sendEvent('PLAY');return false;">play/pause toggle</a><br />
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('mediaspace').sendEvent('LOAD', 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZNXUXujoX4M'); return false;">Video 1</a><br />
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('mediaspace').sendEvent('LOAD', 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gE5tOEU7ymU'); return false;">Video 2</a><br />
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('mediaspace').sendEvent('LOAD', 'http://politicos.biz/stack/playlist.xml'); return false;">Load Playlist</a><br />
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('mediaspace').sendEvent('NEXT'); return false;">Next Video on Playlist</a><br />
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('mediaspace').sendEvent('PREV'); return false;">Previous Video on Playlist</a><br />
```

You'll need to download http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/ and change `jwplayer.js` and `player.swf` (optional) locations. You'll also need to create a [crossdomain.xml](http://x.co/ZEtn) file and place it in the root folder of your domain.

I hope it helps you :)

Live example @ http://x.co/ZEpd